# How to use Grunt/Gulp with pm2?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp, pm2

pm2 is a great tool to manage node apps. How does it work with grunt/glup ?
I didn't find any useful clues after Googling for 20 minutes.

Comment: Please be more specific, do you want to deploy? Do you want to run `gulp` on restart?

Comment: @soyuka deploy. For example, run multiple grunt on server, how to manage these grunt processes like use pm2 to run multiple nodejs processes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question well, it seems you want to deploy your app.

Since pm2 `0.9` deployment can be done with `pm2 deploy` [see README](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/).

In the case of grunt/gulp, I see two options:

1. You've your `node_modules` comitted. Using `pm2 deploy` run your gulp process from the `post-deploy` section:

   ```
   "post-deploy" : "node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js ./GulpFile.js && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json --env production"
   ```
2. Using a basic script that will launch `npm install` for you, you could use the `package.json` to grunt/gulp:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "start": "node server.js",
       "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower -q -s -f install && ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js"
   },
   ```

My gulp generally needs bower to minify scripts so I left it only for example purpose.

You may combine the two options to let `pm2 deploy` install your `npm` scripts and have a `postinstall` script in the `package.json`.

Note that I'm using the relative path to the `gulp` module binary! It's just to avoid an issue if the global module is not installed.

Now, in my opinion to deploy an application in production it's better to simply have a git branch where everything is pre-gulped so that you only clone that branch and you're good to go. It also improves the deploy time, especially if you're running tests with gulp or grunt...

Hope that's clear enough!

Comment: I happend to have a similar problem. the thing is I want to monitor the grunt running process, could you help me on how to do it ?

Comment: How about if you're using `watch` and want the server to reload (read: regulp) on file changes?

Comment: Just use gulp watch instead.

Answer (score 1):

The Reply may be late it must be usefull to others

On the command line do:

```
$ export NODE_ENV=production
```

will setup production environmental

```
$ grunt build
```

will create necessary *min.js* and *min.css*

```
$ pm2 start server.js
```

will load the server with `pm2` , that its a package thats makes sure the node server will restart if an error and will log.